# Selenium get access to text using css

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, automated-tests

I am trying to access text of `table data` using Selenium and then checking if it is equal to given text.

The problem I am facing is `Expected result gets converted to Array with [] brackets`.

How can I convert this to basic string? What code change will help me achieve this?

Below is my code

```
const resultList = element.all(by.css('table tr:nth-of-type(9) [colspan]')); 
expect(resultList.getText()).toEqual("This is data");
```

Output - Error

```
Expected [ 'This is data' ] to equal 'This is data'.
```

Trying to achieve (`Without Brackets []`)

```
Expected  'This is data'  to equal 'This is data'.
```

Comment: Because that's (`resultList`) a list! Use a for loop and check with your value if you have multiple values like this. Or you could just do `expect(resultList[n].getText()).toEqual("This is data");` where **n** is the index of the value you need to check.

Comment: It says `n is not defined`. I do not want this as List as there is just 1 value. What changes do I need to make? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to this -

`expect(element(by.css('table tr:nth-of-type(9) [colspan]')).getText()).toEqual("This is test data.");`